# How do I install presto-admin on Dataproc cluster on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, presto, google-cloud-dataproc

I started my cluster as follows:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters \
      create mycluster \
      --zone us-west1-b \
      --master-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
      --master-boot-disk-size 500 \
      --num-preemptible-workers 5 \
      --worker-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
      --worker-boot-disk-size 500 \
      --scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' \
      --project myproject \
      --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/presto/presto.sh
```

Presto is working GREAT! But 'presto-admin' is not installed. I tried installing using this command:

```
sudo pip install prestoadmin
```

But it's not working 'cause 'pip' is not available. I tried installing 'pip' but ran into Python related issues. I am thinking there might be an easier way to install presto-admin tool on a cluster created on Dataproc. What's the easiest way to install 'presto-admin' on Dataproc?

Comment: Why did someone down vote?

Comment: No idea ... making up for that ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did it for me.

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo apt install python-dev
sudo pip install prestoadmin
```